# Добавление шрифта в css

Tags: css

Представим ситуацию:
Скачал чужой проект с кучей css файлов, выбрал на мой взгляд самый главный из них, добавил туда:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    src: url('~/Content/fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('~/Content/fonts/bebasneue_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

body {
    font-family: bebas_neueregular;
}
```

Пути правильные, но рендерится все равно Times New Roman. Как искать проблему в таком случае?

UPD: я болван, шрифт кириллицу не поддерживал )))

Comment: через отладчик посмотреть, какой шрифт выставлен по факту желаемому элементу. и посмотреть, откуда он тянется

Comment: @lexxl объясните, пожалуйста, как человеку, который впервые это все видит)

Answer (score 1):

Когда подключаешь нестандартный шрифт надо название указывать в скобках:

```
font-family: "bebas_neueregular";
```

Comment: Проверил все комбинации кавычек, результат тот же

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев значит путь неверно к шрифтам указан

Comment: шрифты точно лежат в прописанном каталоге

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, вы в консоли браузера смотрели загружаются ли шрифты точно?

Comment: @Visman да, в консоли он скачивается, в обычной html странице поведение такое же, и шрифт работает корректно, а в проекте почему-то нет

Comment: @Visman вот что консоль говорит font-face не удалось пройти проверку на разрешение внедрения шрифтов OpenType. Необходимо разрешение "Устанавливаемый".